# how do I instruct jquery to perform the jquery function and ignore the native click event?

Tags: jquery

For some reason, I have used hyperlinks to hide/show another div without issues but there is one that is giving me trouble. The problem maybe somewhere else, but I want to rule that that the hyperlink is the problem before I wreak havoc in my script file.

Simple hidden div, that needs to be shown on a click of a hyperlink button.

Like this

```
<a id="addItemTrigger" class="btn-floating">
     <i class="material-icons">add</i>
</a>
<div id="addMediaPlylistsItems" class="col"> Something </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#addMediaPlylistsItems").hide();

   $('#addItemTrigger').click(function (event) {
        return false
        // event.preventDefault();
        $("#addMediaPlylistsItems").show();
    });

});
```

The `return false` stops the hyperlink from closing the drawer/modal. But it also doesn't allow the #addMediaPlylistsItems to show. And the `preventDefault()` does nothing at all. Using `pointer-events: none;` in the css cancels all events on the hyperlink (i.e. hover, clicking, everything).

Any other suggestions?

EDIT

I changed the `<a>` to a `<div>` and it behaves the same way, so it's the click event that is triggering the close of the drawer. Perhaps is not the hyperlink itself and I need to use another event that is not click().

Sorry if this sounds confusing. I'm just trying so many things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: return *after* showing the element, not before.  (or use event.preventDefault.)

Comment: As soon as you return false the function is finished. Return does just that, returns control to what called it.

Comment: Jesus Christ! What is wrong with me? I know this! :facepalming myself: Thanks fellas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the thing what do you want to do but if you want show and hide the content it's better like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#addMediaPlylistsItems").hide();

   $('#addItemTrigger').click(function () {
        $("#addMediaPlylistsItems").toggle();
//toggle = hide and show
    });

});
```

Comment: Oh God, that was so easy...I need to rest. Thanks!

Comment: No worries ahah i was not sure was it about that ahah

Comment: Minor edit to your event. I replaced "slow" with "show"

Comment: Slow allows to get your function slowly on this one it is the content

Comment: try toggle() and toggle("slow") you will see the difference

Comment: I would much rather it was immidiate. The animation slows some other showing behaviors i the order they need to show